# map through array inside of an array of objects

Tags: javascript

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        posts: [{
        question: 'QUESTION',  
        answers: [{
          answer: 'first answer'
        }],
      }],
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>           
    {this.state.posts.map(item => 
          <div>
          <h1> {item.question} </h1>
          {item.answers.map(a => {
             <div> {a.answer} </div>
            })}
           </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Wanted to know why this does not work. It makes sense to me that item.answers.map would map through the answers array.

[project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-object-into-an-array-inside-of-an-array-of-objects?embed=1&file=index.js)

Comment: You need to return `<div> {a.answer} </div>` in your `item.answers.map`. Or remove the surrounding curly braces to have implicit return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not returning `<div> {a.answer} </div>`, because the arrow function is defined using curly braces (a "block body") instead of parentheses (a "concise body" with an implicit return).

Try this:

```
{item.answers.map(a => (
    <div> {a.answer} </div>
 ))}
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block
>   body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the
>   explicit `return` value. In a block body, you must use an explicit
>   return statement.